# Spring scala Example Projects are available?

Tags: spring, scala

I am new in scala spring and i learn about it just now.

the scala spring example projects are not available. I search about it a lot ..

The Spring scala sample projects are available anywhere?..

```
I search a lot but can't get it..

if any one know about these please mention below as a answer?..
```

Comment: https://github.com/GrahamLea/scala-spring-hibernate-maven-webapp

Comment: Thanks.. @GrahamLea this is what am looking for.. really

Comment: Official support: http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala and https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-scala

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here're some example projects:
[scala, mvn and springmvc template](https://github.com/zohebsait/scala-springmvc-thymeleaf-bootstrap-template)
[petclinic sample,again mvn](http://code.google.com/p/scala-spring/) 
[mvn tutorial](http://grahamhackingscala.blogspot.com/2010/01/scala-spring-hibernate-maven-webapp-how.html)
[sbt setup](http://fisharefriendsus.blogspot.com/2011/09/setting-up-scala-sbt-scalatest-etc.html)
Of course I would recommend not to use spring at all with scala, and use cake-pattern for DI + squirrel or scala-query for persistence, but it's up to you what framework to use.

Comment: why do you recommend not to use spring with scala? Spring is not just a DI container.

Comment: exactly! What it is except DI? Data Access - few people uses hibernate in scala. AOP - mostly not needed in scala. Request scopes - mostly not applicable. Configuration library - there're better scala alternatives, including custom DSLs. Validation, Data Binding, and Type Conversion - native scala libraries provide better scala support. MVC framework - people usually use play or lift. Other libraries under spring umbrella mostly fix java problems which are non existent in scala. It's ok to use spring with scala if it's a legacy project or a specific business requirement.

Comment: Most examples that I have seen about DI in scala used scala itself to configure the application. For example, you want to change the implementation of some class to another. Can you do this without recompilation of any class? Also spring offers a common way to solve problems. Does scala have this? There are a lot of scala libraries for different purposes, but you have to know the ideology each of them to use them in the right way, I don't think that it is comfortably.Wwhy AOP is not need in scala, what abot transactions, security, caching?

Comment: everything is done in pure scala itself. "Change implementation of some class to another" I can do it in pure java: `FooInterface instance = new FooImplementation();`. If you are talking about byte-code level enchantments than it is mostly used in spring to create dynamic proxy that has transactional or other properties. But in scala you just mix-in traits at compile time to achieve almost the same functionality, or use macros. Again, you can use AOP in scala without spring. Spring is a good framework I do not criticize it, but the same is achieved simpler in scala that's all.

Comment: what is your usual scala stack to build projects, I want to review that libs?

Comment: I used  spray+squeryl (as a config db, main was cassandra) +lift-json+akka; play2 + slick; play2 + reactive mongo and elastic-search +akka. I've used cake pattern for DI everywhere. In one project configuration was done through custom DSL but now I can't be bothered and use typesafe config lib. I usually include scalaz but never use it)). Also I use scalatest for unit testing.

Answer (score 2):

I've put together a bare minimum project that bootstraps [Scala and Spring using Maven](https://dimitrisli.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/scala-spring-maven-example/).